# length of the values of any given key

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, nodes

I am trying to create a function that will return the degrees of a given node in a graph. I keep running into the error unhashable type: 'list' in my degree function and I'm not really sure why this is happening since I am not trying to assign a list as a key, which is what causes this error as far as I understand. All I need to do is get the length of the values for any given key I input into degree. I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I've been staring at this long enough to lose my mind and would appreciate a fresh set of eyes.

```
from collections import defaultdict
graph = defaultdict(dict)

def addEdge(node1, node2): #adds edges to the graph
    # create an empty list for a key node
    if node1 not in graph:
        graph[node1] = []
    if node2 not in graph:
        graph[node2] = []
    graph[node1].append(node2) #adds the edges to each other
    graph[node2].append(node1)

def degree(node):
  for node in graph.items(): 
    degrees = len(graph[node])
    return degrees

def select():
  weights = []
  for i in graph:
    weights.append(degree(i))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see with your code is here:

```
for node in graph.items(): 
    degrees = len(graph[node])
```

You are iterating over each value returned by `graph.items()`, treating each one as though it is a key in your `graph` dictionary.  You expect that iterating on `graph.items()` gives you each of the nodes in `graph`.  That's not what it does.  `items()` returns a tuple containing both the key and the value for each item in the dictionary.  The second item in each of those tuples is a list.
That's the list that the error message is complaining about.  What I think you mean to do is iterate over the keys in `graph`. Replacing `graph.items()` with `graph.keys()` should resolve your problem:

```
for node in graph.keys(): 
    degrees = len(graph[node])
```

I see two other problems...

Your `degree` function takes `node` as a parameter, but you use that same variable name in your iteration.  So the parameter you're passing to `degree` isn't being used.

Another problem I see is that the overall logic in the `degree` function makes no sense.  You start to iterate over the items in `graph`, but then you return from the function at the end of the first iteration.  So you aren't really iterating.  Maybe your indentation is wrong and your `return` statement should only execute after all iterations have happened.  But then you're setting `degrees` over and over, so your iterations are happening, but only the last one has any affect.

In `select`, you're already iterating over `graph`.  So what I'm guessing you want is to not have a `for` loop in `degree`, but rather just have that function return the length of the list associated with the passed in `node`.  So I think `degree` should really be:

```
def degree(node):
    return len(graph[node])
```

Comment: After replacing with your suggestion I still have the same issue

Comment: Sorry for giving you a only half right answer.  Using `values()` wasn't the right answer.  I meant to say `keys()` instead.  See the update to my answer.  I bet changing `items()` to `keys()` solves your current problem.

Comment: Cool.  See my other comments.  I only just now finished tweaking them.  I'm curious if I had your intentions right....if my final version of your `degree` function is indeed what you actually want.

Comment: you were pretty much right, I realized the iteration problem soon after and I ended up combining degree and select to avoid it and now everything is fine

Comment: cool beans.  glad I could help.  Feel free to give me that green check mark and/or an upvote to show that I answered your question in a way that helped you out.